# Not loading into variable from database in the index section of the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I go to the rails console and type in:

```
irb(main):018:0> search_filter = Search.order("created_at").last  
I get back:  
Search Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches"   ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  
=> #<Search id: 9, user_id: 2, postnumer_id: "170", matssvaedi_id: "", ist120_id: "", gotuheiti: "",  
dagsetning_from: nil, dagsetning_to: nil, byggingarar_from: nil, byggingarar_to: nil,  
fjoldiherbergja_from: nil, fjoldiherbergja_to: nil, flatarmal_from: nil, flatarmal_to: nil,  
created_at: "2014-10-10 11:56:55", updated_at: "2014-10-10 11:56:55">
```

This is what I would expect, the last record in the Search table based on the creation date.

However if I put
search_filter = Search.order("created_at").last
as the first line in the index section of my SearchesController
and the next line is
puts search_filter
I get the following output in the Rails server console when I press submit:

```
#<Search:0x007f3ccc6d8c78>
```

Can someone please help with explaining why the output is not the same. I have been looking at this for a while and I am not getting it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `puts` you are printing the variable. You are printing the String representation of the instance variable "Search" to see something specific you could do `puts search_filter.property`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. searching led me to as_json which solved my problem.